# What can you do with embedded GPS locally?

Tags: geotagging, windows, linux, gps, software-recommendation

The [Sony Alpha SLT-A55](http://www.neocamera.com/camera.php?id=148) made its way to me and it has a built-in GPS. Each photo is marked with its GPS coordinates, elevation and orientation. I am aware that if I upload such a photo to Picasa or other web-services like Panoramio, then I'll be able to see a map showing the location where a picture was taken.

The question is, what can I do with this locally? Meaning, on my own computer without uploading my photos anywhere. What kind of programs exist to use the location data in a meaningful or interesting way?

For my specific case, Linux and Windows software are fine (I run the latter in a VM under the former). Mac-only software won't be of any use to me.

Comment: "made its way to me"? - I wish a $900 piece of equipment would randomly show up at my doorstep. ;)

Comment: Hmmm; although mac-only software won't be of use to you, it might be to someone. In which case we might as well not tag this post with any particular OS.....

Comment: @rfusca- It's the first A55, the serial number is 1! Yes, ONE, preceded by a many zeros. It has been making the rounds among members of the press, so it's not entirely random, sorry.

Comment: Maybe post a raw photo so I can see if any of my software knows what to do with the GPS info?

Comment: @mattdm - Yeah, I had some doubts about asking for a platform-specific answer to get the one I needed, or asking for ALL possible answers and simply read the ones that are relevant. I chose the former, it will make the voting simpler and more inline with my needs.

Comment: Upon request :) - Sample JPEG image straight from the Sony Alpha SLT-A55: http://www.neocamera.com/review/sony/a55/samples/DSC00032.JPG

Comment: @drewbenn - How did you assess the accuracy? I used Geotag to visualize the coordinates and it seems accurate. There is a note in the manual that says accuracy is diminished near tall-buildings, which is NOT the case for this photo. The camera also supports the use of GPS assist data which must be downloaded onto the camera each month (more or less). I have not tried it yet.

Comment: @drewbenn - I assume Geotag does pretty much the same but it got me right in front of center of the building (on the correct side) which is where the photo was taken. Here's the link software: http://geotag.sourceforge.net

Comment: @drewbenn - Thanks for reporting back. I'm still making slow progress with this, so discounting issues is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasa has a Geo-Tag feature that allows you to use Google Earth to write EXIF location data. You get to see some small picture thumbnails on the Google Earth's map - it's nice to see photos you've taken while traveling to a certain area.

I believe this is possible with pictures already containing EXIF location data - check out this [link](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=43900).

This does not involve uploading photos anywhere (note I'm not speaking about Picasa Web, but about the Windows-based client), but it does require Internet access.

Answer (score 6):

Lightroom 4 will look at GPS data and pulls Google maps to show you where you've taken your pictures and lets you search/filter by location, among other things.

Comment: This solution didn't exist when this question was asked, but has become the main reason why I find GPS data capture useful in my daily workflow. It works excellent!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question on behalf of a friend who showed me [Geotag](http://geotag.sourceforge.net). This is a Java software that can show you any number of pictures on a map in a browser winder.

No need to upload anything, it fetches the maps from Google Maps and uses a local http server to display them. So, it is one possibility that matches what I am looking for.

It can show the point and direction where pictures where taken, although for some reason it does not get the direction information from the A55. According the spec, the camera records GPS position, elevation and orientation.

What's missing is that I'd like to do the opposite, instead of going from image to location, to go from a location to images around it, given a certain proximity metric. That would require a software that indexes all my images like Lightroom.

Comment: Yes, the compass orientation is recorded as well. There are currently 4 cameras that do that: Casio H20G, Fuji F550 EXR, Sony SLT-A55 and Sony HX5.

Answer (score 2):

I've been religiously geocoding my photos for a number of years - I find it handy for scouting locaitons -- so if I get a photo of some bluebells thta have gone past their best, I can know exactly where to go to get the shot for the next year's season.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to see they are including gps chips in cameras now!

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I personally geotag my photos when I'm on vacation so I can remember where I went. I can create a high level view of the path I took through a city (on a day level) or a wider view during a whole trip. My camera doesn't geotag, but my iphone has software to create paths and I have a lightroom plugin to match up photos with a path (Jeffrey’s Geoencoding Plugin).

As far as offline software, I use picassa to see my photos on a map without uploading them. This still requires an internet connection to access google maps. Personally viewing photos on a map is the only use for geotagging I have thought of, and I would imagine it is the typical use case. I'd love to hear other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Aperture 3's "Places" feature can show you your photos on a map:

http://www.digital-photography-school.com/using-aperture-3%E2%80%99s-places
http://www.apple.com/aperture/whats-new.html#places

Comment: For the record, iPhoto has the same feature.

Answer (score 0):

Digikam has good geodata support. There is a built in map and other functionality.

It is written for Linux but also runs on windows.

www.digikam.org